# Debugging Blazor in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I am trying to debug my blazor page. I run Chrome with the following:

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\blazor-chrome-debug" https://localhost:7025/ --remote-allow-origins=*
```

After trying to enter debugger by shift+alt+D I get this:

[image: Error]

I cannot enter any page with the debugger. What might cause this issue?